# Python equivalent to Matlab's copulafit function

Tags: python, matlab, statistics, probability, data-fitting

Is there a Python equivalent to Matlab's function [`copulafit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/copulafit.html)? Not necessarily in its entirety, but at least the Gaussian and t-copula and their negative log-likelihoods would be fine.

I'm aware of a few copula packages, but not sure which offers the highest resemblance to Matlab's code, shown below. I would actually prefer an authoritative implementation, like how `numpy` and `scipy` are rigorously high-quality. Better yet, a direct python translation of `copulafit`, or parts of.

Comment: This package seems to do the job: https://copulae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Looking at its source code at the following link, I do not see a function that resembles `copulafit`, containing what the above does all-in-one. Do you know which .py file it is? https://github.com/DanielBok/copulae/tree/master/copulae

Comment: Ah, but have you considered that it may not exist? Generally python and MATLAB are not 1to1, simply you have the tools to get the same thing, not in the same way. There is a reason why MATLAB can still charge tons of money for their license, and its because often they have this types of functions....

Comment: you'd be surprised how much `scikit-learn` for Python directly mimics many R machine learning packages. I'm sure much of `numpy` and `scipy` borrow alot from Matlab's statistical functions

Comment: Here is a list of all of the Python equivalents to basic functions in Matlab. you bet they are directly lifting from Matlab http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-python-xref.pdf

Comment: Yeah thanks. Do you have a list of the ones that are not the same? because that is kinda longer. Not sure if you are trying to generalize your argument, but its not valid, plenty of methods are not direct translation between the two. Ive been using MATLAB for 10 years and python/numpy for around 6, and there are many examples, *especially in libraries* where the comparison does not apply.

Comment: "I would actually prefer an authoritative implementation...Better yet, a direct python translation of copulafit, or parts of." Direct translation isn't considered an authoritative implementation. Also you don't have permission to distribute parts of a proprietary software like that function body.